# Scala 2.11 override things form an abstract class

Tags: scala, overriding, scala-2.11

I have a question concerning Scala override (as my title suggests)

Now I have the following classes/traits:

```
trait FSM {def transitionGraph:Map[String,(JsValue,FSM)]
abstract class AClass: FSM { def transitionGraph }

class Class extends AClass{ override def transitionGraph ... } <-- Wont work

trait OverrideTrait extends AClass { abstract override def transitionGraph } <-- works
class NewClass extends OverrideTrait { } <--- Works, I can use the overridden transitionGraph
```

My question is: Why can I not override things from an abstract class. Is it because I am never allowed to instantiate an abstract class. Thus the behavior :

```
val AClass class = new Class
```

is never allowed to happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example wouldn't compile. But it should work once you corrected a few things:

```
trait FSM {def transitionGraph:Map[String,(JsValue,FSM)]}

abstract class AbstractClass extends FSM { def transitionGraph }

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{ def transitionGraph = ??? }

val someClass: AbstractClass = new ConcreteClass
```

Comment: @MarcHPunkt Yes, but for it all to work it should all compile. Did you try what I wrote in my answer? And did it work for you?

Comment: I am at work now. I will try it as soon as I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of stuff omitted from the code you've given, so I'm not sure I get the question, but here's something similar that does compile:

```
trait FSM { def transitionGraph: String }
abstract class AClass extends FSM { def transitionGraph: String }

class Class extends AClass { override def transitionGraph = ??? }

trait OverrideTrait extends AClass { override def transitionGraph = ??? }
class NewClass extends OverrideTrait { }
```

Does this help at all?